# Mounting EFS using .ebextensions file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-efs, automount

I am deploying a PHP app using AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I would like to use EFS I've already built. I'm using a .ebextension folder using following link as guide:

https://github.com/awsdocs/elastic-beanstalk-samples/blob/master/configuration-files/aws-provided/instance-configuration/storage-efs-mountfilesystem.config

I have configured the storage-efs-mountfilesystem.config file in .ebextension folder file:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    FILE_SYSTEM_ID: fs-12345678
    MOUNT_DIRECTORY: '/efs'
```

When I look in my ec2 instance spun up from elastic beanstalk, I do not see the EFS mounted. I am trying to figure out what might be the issue here? Wouldn't it be better to have EFS details in a file in .ebextension folder so it can be persistently mounted when software is deployed regularly?

Comment: You are writing ".ebextension". The folder should be called `.ebextensions`. Can you confirm you are using correct folder in your project?

Comment: Apologies, yes the folder is called .ebextensions.

Comment: Do you get any errors? Have you inspected EB logs?

Comment: I'm new to ELB, so unfamiliar with the logs. I have downloaded the zip of the logs. Is there specific log I should look at?

Comment: Don't remember which single log could be of interest. You can search through all of them to quickly look for ERRORs, "commands", EFS or any similar keyword.

Comment: Yes, that's the issue. Are you running Amazon Linux 1 or 2?

Comment: Hi. Just wonder if you had any luck with the issues?

Comment: Thank you! I deployed to Amazon Linux 1 and was successfully able to mount efs automatically.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help. Acceptance of this answer would also be appreciated if it was helpful :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the additional information from comments.

The issue is due to:

```
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config: No such file or directory
```

This file exists only for EB environments running **Amazon Linux 1**, not for **Amazon Linux 2**. Since `PHP 7.4 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.0.` is used, the `storage-efs-mountfilesystem.config` fails, as it requires Amazon Linux 1.

In this situation there are generally **two options** to rectify the issue:

1. Use Amazon Linux 1.
2. Or adapt `storage-efs-mountfilesystem.config` to work with Amazon Linux 2.

It should be noted that there are **many differences** between Amazon Linux 1 and 2. General steps to migrate from the older to newer version are below:

- [Migrating your Elastic Beanstalk Linux application to Amazon Linux 2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.migration-al.html)